# How can I pass an object from my view to my controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to download an Excel file when the user clicks on an Excel button. This is my `Model` and `Object`:

```cs
List<VMStockScreenerModel> listofStockScreener = (List<VMStockScreenerModel>)TempData["StockScreener"];
TempData["StockScreener"] = listofStockScreener;
```

This is the Excel button in my view:

```
<div class="col-md-1 padding-fx text-left" id="btn_FilterStocks">
    <span onclick="DownloadFilterStocks(@listofStockScreener.ToList());" class="pull-right icon-merge" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Download">
        <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>                        
        <i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i>                 
    </span>                                                     
</div>
```

And here is my `OnClick` handler:

```js
function DownloadFilterStocks() {
    debugger;
    var Obj = [@listofStockScreener];
    Obj = JSON.stringify({ 'Obj': Obj });
    var urls = '@(Html.Raw(Url.Action("Download_StockScreener","Home", new { Obj = "_Obj_"},Request.Url.Scheme)))'.replace("_Obj_", Obj);                   
}
```

Controller Code

```
public FileResult Download_StockScreener(VMStockScreenerModel Obj)
        {
            try
            {
                string fileName = string.Empty;
                string filePath = string.Empty;
                string fileName_filePath = string.Empty;


                fileName_filePath = StockScreener_DownloadExcel(Obj);
                if (fileName_filePath.Contains("@"))
                {
                    filePath = fileName_filePath.Split('@')[0];
                    fileName = fileName_filePath.Split('@')[1];
                }
                if (fileName != "")
                {
                    //return File(filePath, "text/csv", fileName);

                }

                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Logging("HomeController => Download_StockScreener", ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);

            } return null;
        }
```

Comment: can u show us the controller code?

Comment: Hello, and welcome. I’d recommend viewing the source of your HTML as output to your browser. I think you’ll find that your `listofStockScreener` object is not writing to the markup or JavaScript as you’re expecting. Likely, it’s writing as the name of the class, not an actual list of anything. Instead, you’ll likely want to do a `for` loop over your `listofStockScreener` and display an Excel button for each one—assuming, of course, that you want to be able to download a file for each `VMStockScreenerModel` instance in the `listofStockScreener`.

Comment: Also, assuming you want a download per `VMStockScreenerModel`, what property on the `VMStockScreenerModel` corresponds to your Excel file? And what format is that in? That is, is it a path to the Excel document? A unique identifier for the file? Or is it actually a reference to a binary or file object in C#? This will have an impact on how you write out your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing the whole code for you, i hope i can guide you to the answer by suggesting you the steps you need to take for making your solution work:

1. Instead of `span`, make the element an anchor `a`.
2. Render the anchor's URL server side (MVC view) without the query string part. Example: `<a href="www.mydomain.com/Stocks/ExportToExcel" onclick="DownloadFilterStocks(this)">Export</a>`
3. In the anchor's click event, do the following:

```
    function DownloadFilterStocks(elem) {
        debugger;
        var Obj = [@listofStockScreener];

        var $elem = $(elem);

        //this converts JS object to query string
        var qParams = $.param(Obj); 

        //append query string to the anchor's base url
        var newUrl = $elem.attr('href') + '?' + qParams; 

        //assign new url
        $elem.attr('href', newUrl);
    }
```

The way this will work is:

1. When the export link is clicked, JS code will be executed before server-side execution.
2. JS will update the URL/href with the query string
3. Server-side code will be executed with the new URL

Hope that helps you out. I ended up writing few codes anyway.

Note: My answer assumes that your server-side code is a working code.